# What happen when we do AND operation of 4 byte number with 2 byte number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write a piece of code to extract every single byte of data out of a 4 byte integer
after little bit of searching i actually found the code with which this can be achieved , but i am just curious to know why it behaves the way output is created , below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getByte(int x, int n);

void main()
{
    int x = 0xAABBCCDD;
    int n;

    for (n=0; n<=3; n++) {
        printf("byte %d of 0x%X is 0x%X\n",n,x,getByte(x,n));
    }

}

// extract byte n from word x
// bytes numbered from 0 (LSByte) to 3 (MSByte)
int getByte(int x, int n)
{
    return (x >> (n << 3)) & 0xFF;
}
```

**Output:**

```
byte 0 of 0xAABBCCDD is 0xDD
byte 1 of 0xAABBCCDD is 0xCC
byte 2 of 0xAABBCCDD is 0xBB
byte 3 of 0xAABBCCDD is 0xAA
```

the result is self explanatory but why the compiler didn't converted 0xFF into 0x000000FF , since it has to perform AND operation with a 4 byte number and instead generated the output consisting of only 1 byte of data and not 4 byte of data.

Comment: The specific answer is [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)

Comment: both `0xFF` and `0x000000FF` have the same type and same value in C. It's just the output format is different

Comment: user1597336, Curious, if format had been  `"%d"` instead of  `"0x%X"`, would you have expected `"255"` or `"0000000255"` for the 4-byte `int` return from `getByte(x,n)`?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler did convert `0xFF` to `0x000000FF`. Since the value is an integer constant, `0xFF` gets converted internally to a 32-bit value (assuming that your platform has a 32-bit `int`).

Note that the values you get back, i.e. `0xDD`, `0xCC`, `0xBB`, and `0xAA`, are also `int`s, so they have leading zeros as well, so you actually get `0x000000DD`, `0x000000CC`, and so on. Leading zeros do not get printed automatically, though, so if you wish to see them, you'd need to change the format string to request leading zeros to be included:

```
for (n=0; n<=3; n++) {
    printf("byte %d of 0x%08X is 0x%08X\n", n, x, getByte(x,n));
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/NM8sth)

Comment: Minor detail: In C, `0xFF` is an integer _constant_, not _literal_ - in this case, of type `int`.    C's 2 _literals_: _string literals_ and _compound literals_ can have their address taken.   `0xFF` cannot.  In others languages like C++, `0xFF` can have its address taken and is there called a literal.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Thanks for the info.. please share the statement for printing the complete number with leading zeros.

Comment: I just ran the below piece of code with the mentioned format specifier online at
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

printf("byte %d of 0x%X is 0x08%X\n",n,x,getByte(x,n));

but instead of the usual output i am getting the output as - 
byte 0 of 0xAABBCCDD is 0x08DD

Comment: @user1597336 Sorry, I put `%` in a wrong spot, it should have been `0x%08X`. Please see the update and a demo link.

Answer (score 3):

The output **is** a 4-byte number, but `printf("%X")` doesn't print any leading zero digits.

If you do `printf("foo 0x%X bar\n", 0x0000AA)` you'll get `foo 0xAA bar` as output.

Answer (score 1):

0xFF and 0x000000FF are both exactly the same thing, by default the formatting will drop the leading 0's if you want to print them in your output, you just need to specify it:

```
printf("byte %d of 0x%X is 0x08%X\n",n,x,getByte(x,n));
```

But since you are printing Bytes I'm not quite sure why you would expect the leading 0's.